# Find the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a}_{n}$ if ${s}_{n}\in \mathbb{N}$ is ${s}_{2n-1}=1$ and ${s}_{2n}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the series   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a}_{n}$   if   ${s}_{n}\in \mathbb{N}$  is  ${s}_{2n-1}=1$ and  ${s}_{2n}=0$

I used ${a}_{n}={s}_{n}-{s}_{n-1}\Rightarrow {a}_{2n}={s}_{2n}-{s}_{2n-1}\Leftrightarrow {a}_{2n}=-1$ but it doesn't seem to end up anywhere. There must be a way to find  ${a}_{n}$  so I can find the series(I mean write the formula).  Any suggestions?

Thank you.

edit: The answer is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)}^{n-1}$ but i don't know how we get there.

Comment: Start with $a_n = \sin(n\pi/2)$ and massage.

Comment: You found the even coefficients now you need to find the odd ones

Comment: Not an answer, really, but I do not have the right to post a comment yet... I do not understand your question : are $a_n$ and $s_n$ the same ?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track:

$a_1 = s_1 = 1$

$a_2 = s_2-s_1 = -1$

$a_3 = s_3-s_2 = 1$

$\dots$

$a_{2n-1} = s_{2n-1} -s_{2n-2} = 1$

$a_{2n} = s_{2n} -s_{2n-1} = -1$

Answer (score 0):

If $s_n$ denotes the the sequence of partial sum then the series will not be covergent. As  the series will be covergent if and only if the sequence of it's partial sum converges. Here two subsequence of the sequence of partial sums converge to two different limits. So clearly the sequence of partial sum will not converge.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it converges or not, I just want to find the formula which actually is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)}^{n-1}$    but I don't know how.